What's wrong with this Java-code? I have several errors running it
I have tried to run this Java-code but there are some errors in it. I wanted to set default parameters of the class and then class constructor. But something is wrong in it. Help me please to solve this problem.
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Vehicle bmw_m5 = new Vehicle("BMW", "M5_competition", 2012);
        System.out.println(bmw_m5.name);      System.out.println(bmw_m5.model);        System.out.println(bmw_m5.release_year);
    }
}



class Vehicle{
    String name;
    String model;
    int release_year;

    this.name = "undefined";
    this.model = "undefined";
    this.release_year = 0;

    Vehicle(String name, String model, int release_year){
        this.name = name;
        this.model = model;
        this.release_year = release_year;}
}

Here is the code itself.

"there are some errors in it" Please edit your question, and show us the errors that you see.

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Vehicle bmw_m5 = new Vehicle("BMW", "M5_competition", 2012);
        System.out.println(bmw_m5.name);      
        System.out.println(bmw_m5.model);        
        System.out.println(bmw_m5.release_year);
    }
}



class Vehicle{
    String name = "undefined";
    String model = "undefined";
    int release_year = 0;

    Vehicle(String name, String model, int release_year){
        this.name = name;
        this.model = model;
        this.release_year = release_year;}
}

Should work if you remove "this" outside of methods and specify your default values when you declare the variables.
Depending on the use case you also might want to look into access modifiers.
So for example you could make the instance variables private. Afterwards create getter/setter methods for each variable. A default constructor that initializes the object with default values and a constructor as you alreade have. If an objekt is then already created you could later on modifiy its instance variable via setters.

It works. But how can I create an empty object without specifying his parameters, so that default values of the class are called? Vehicle bmw_m5 = new Vehicle(); doesn't work because it asks for parameters

Thanks for your help. I found the soulution.

@Illusion I would suggest Vehicle() { this("undefined", "undefined", 0); } Note you do not assign variables based on the results of calling a setter. this.var1 = setVar1() -- please don't suggest that.

Just put the values on the same line
String name = "undefined";
String model = "undefined";

public Vehicle(... 

Integers already default to zero
You cannot use this directly within the class body, outside a function

Yes, it works. But how can I create an empty object without specifying his parameters, so that default values of the class are called? Vehicle bmw_m5 = new Vehicle(); doesn't work because it asks for parameters

@GulovYusuf: Create a default constructor. A default constructor is one that takes no parameters:  public Vehicle () { name = "undefined"; model = "undefined"; release_year = 0; }
